# Angle $\cos(\theta)$ between vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}+\vec{e}$, with fixed $\vec{a}$ and random $\vec{e}$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Say we have ${\bf{b}}$=$\bf{a}$+$\bf{e}$, where $\bf{a}$ is a fixed complex vector and $\bf{e}$ is a random vector. Each entry of $\bf{e}$ is a zero mean Gaussian variable with variance $\sigma^2$.

I want to calculate the expected value of the inner product $E[cos\theta]=E[\frac{|{\bf{a}}^H{{\bf{b}}}|}{||{\bf{a}}|| . ||{{\bf{b}}}||}]$. I guess it should be a function of $\sigma^2$. Are there any analytical solution or bounds for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The PDF of the cosine of your angle, $\cos\left(\theta\right)$, is that of the pearson correlation coefficient.